# No Wi-Fi adapter found RTL8852A

Tags: linux, wifi, gnome, manjaro, realtek

I've installed Manjaro-Gnome v.21.2.2 on my HP Laptop-15s-eq0005ua. The internal WiFi adapter is not working. After some Google researches, I found that the adapter is a `Realtek RTL8852A`

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
 
Network Controller [0280]: Realter Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device[10ec:a85a]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e2]
```

Where I can download the driver for the device and how I can install it to my Manjaro distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the product:vendor ID (`10ec:a85a`) reported by your `lspci` command, the WiFi adapter is actually Realtek RTL8852A: a new, 802.11ax-capable adapter.

The correct Linux kernel module for it would be `rtw89`, which was added to the main kernel source in 2021-10-13, so it's a very new driver.

[Here's the part of the `rtw89` driver code that causes the module to be loaded  for Realtek product ID `a85a`.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/pci.c#n3044)

Manjaro-Gnome Linux v.21.2.2 seems to have kernel version 5.15 as standard. Unfortunately, the `rtw89` driver was added in kernel version 5.16. [But it looks like the `linux516` package has already reached Manjaro's stable branch](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/stable-update-2022-01-23-opensearch-kernels-kde-software-cinnamon-pipewire-mesa-gnome-libreoffice/99878), so it should be a simple matter of selecting that kernel package for installation in Manjaro's package manager tool and rebooting.

The `rtw89` driver also needs a firmware file, which can be found [in the linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtw89). You should place that file as `/lib/firmware/rtw89/rtw8852a_fw.bin` on your system.

(I'm not a Manjaro user, so anyone knowing anything noteworthy in cases like this, feel free to comment or edit!)

Comment: Then should I update Manjaro to get the new driver?

Comment: [Apparently so.](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/stable-update-2022-01-23-opensearch-kernels-kde-software-cinnamon-pipewire-mesa-gnome-libreoffice/99878) Since it looks like the `linux516` kernel package has already reached Manjaro's "stable branch", you might only need to use Manjaro's package management tools to install it, and reboot.